# Запятая в сочетании "больше(,) чем"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнение

**Больше(,) чем фото.**
**Больше(,) чем образование.**

Есть ли в таких заголовках сравнение? Ставится ли запятая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятые не нужны.

***Больше чем фото

Больше чем образование***

> *Поэт в России – **больше, чем** поэт…* Е. Евтушенко, Молитва перед поэмой.
>
> *…Есть люди… которые смыслят в музыке **не больше, чем** некоторые животные…* М. Булгаков, Театральный роман.

В этих примерах есть сравниваемые понятия: *поэт в России – поэт; люди – животные*.

> ...при отсутствии сравниваемых понятий слова «(не) более / больше чем» образуют с последующими словами неразложимое сочетание (единый член предложения), не требующее постановки знаков препинания.

Источник: [**(НЕ) БОЛЕЕ / БОЛЬШЕ, ЧЕМ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_68) (Грамота.ру).

P. S. Если это заголовки, то точки в конце не ставятся.