# Нужна ли запятая в "не более чем"?

Tags: запятые, сравнительный-оборот

> Ты для меня не более(,) чем друг.

Нужна ли запятая? Ведь это по сути сравнительный оборот? "Ты" – "друг".

Comment: "Ты" не сравнивается с "другом", а "ты" и есть "друг". Так что я не понял, где здесь сравнительный оборот.

Comment: @Nektoid
 Почему не сравнивается?  Можно быть более чем другом. Но потом этот вариант отрицается, и в итоге получается "друг". Но сравнение все-таки было...

Comment: @Чистый Арри Подобный вопрос только что обсуждался, там можно найти и соответствующее правило https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471220/Запятая-в-сочетании-больше-чем  Фактически смысл такой: Ты для меня просто друг, не больше. Поэтому нет запятой.

Comment: @Sharon Чё-т я не пойму. *"Поэтому нет запятой"* – где? Вот интересно... В данном предложении почему-то не просится запятая, хотя оно похоже на "Поэт в России – больше, чем поэт".

Comment: @Александр Стрелец
 Александр, я отвечаю на ваш комментарий в поле ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ***Ты для меня не более чем друг.***

Запятой нет, ***не более чем*** – это устойчивое сочетание, но его структура включает **сравнительный союз ЧЕМ**.

Для проверки сочетание можно **убрать** из предложения, смысл сказанного при этом не изменится: ***ты для меня только друг**.*

2. Аналогично: ***Ты для меня более чем друг.*** Здесь также **устойчивое сочетание,** запятой нет, но убрать "более чем" мы не можем, иначе смысл изменится. Здесь мы говорим: твой статус выше, имея в виду что-то иное.

**Вопрос № 243255**
Нужна запятая: больше(,) чем друг? Спасибо.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка: Запятую ставить не нужно: ***больше чем друг.***

3. Но предложение можно построить **и по образцу сравнения**: Ты значим/значишь для меня не больше, чем друг. Пропущенное сказуемое (значит/значим) меняет грамматику конструкции, теперь это обычное сравнительное предложение, где **есть сравнение**: персонаж (ты) сравнивается с другом.
4. Иногда различить эти варианты трудно, например: ***Поэт в России – больше, чем поэт.***

Здесь сказуемого тоже нет, а запятая ставится. Но это предложение можно считать **неполным**, так как пропущенное сказуемое обозначено тире: *Поэт в России **значит** больше, чем (просто) поэт.*

**Вывод.** Устойчивые выражения указанного вида не так просты, и к ним нельзя подходить формально. Нужен и смысловой анализ, и внимание к структуре предложения.