# «Поэт в России – больше чем поэт». Нужна запятая перед «чем»?

Tags: пунктуация

«Поэт в России – больше чем поэт». Нужна запятая перед «чем»? Склоняюсь, что нет. Но в интернете везде с запятой...

Comment: [Запятая в сочетании «больше(,) чем»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471220/Запятая-в-сочетании-больше-чем/471221#471221).

Comment: А что сравнивается с чем?

Comment: Там всё написано. И Грамота.ру всегда в помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По смыслу понятно, что поэт в России сравнивается с поэтом вообще, поэтому запятая нужна